# Specify the entity in 404 response when retrieve null data from entity symfony

Tags: symfony

I implemented an API and I have some problems when returning the 404 Response. I want that when the id that I provided doens't exist in the database, to return a 404 response with message:

```
"The entity" . $entity " with id: " . $id . "not found. ".
```

The problem is that I don't know how to display the $entity because I use the entityManager for taking the data from the entity, but when the returned data is null I don't have any reference regarding the entity. My 404 function:

```
 public function response404Exception($entity, $id)
{
    $response = new Response();
    if (!$entity){
        $response->setContent('Entity: '. " for id " . $id . "not found.");
        $response->setStatusCode('404');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

and the controller function that retrieves the data and call the 404 function if the data is null:

```
public function getProductsAction($productId)
{
    /**
     * @var object $rooms
     */
    $sizes = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product\Size')
        ->findBy(['product' => $productId]);

    $response404 = $this->response404Exception($sizes, $productId);

    return ($response404->getStatusCode() == 404) ? $response404 : $this->getSerializedEntityResponse($sizes) ;
}
```

How to display the initial message when the $sizes is null?

```
 "The entity product with id [ ..] not found."
```

And also, if I have a function in controller taht retrieves data without accessing with a parameter, how to change the function 404 in order the message 404 to be something like:

```
  "The entity product not found."
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass It in a string like this:

```
$response404 = $this->response404Exception('UBBBuildingBundle:Product\Size', $productId);
```

Or

```
$response404 = $this->response404Exception('Size', $productId);
```

Another way is to use `get_class` like this:

```
$response404 = $this->response404Exception(get_class($sizes), $productId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just count $sizes

> return (count($sizes) === 0) ? $response404 : $this->getSerializedEntityResponse($sizes) ;